# Email chatter followers on every post to record

Tags: apex, email, chatter

I want to email all the followers of a record anytime anyone posts to the chatter feed. I assumed this would be simple but it doesnt seem to be built into the system?

It seems like im gonna have to write an apex trigger to do it?  what is the best way to write the trigger so it works for any record type?

Update: this is what i have so far.  Seems to work.  Lingering questions remain:

- Are their any dangers in this approach?
- how do i get entity information from use ParentID?  how do i know which object it is?  I dont need much just the title I think.
- This method doesnt seem to trigger emails from feed updates posted to the feed, is there anyway to turn those on?
- How do i use a letterhead in these emails?
- Shouldnt there be a built in way to turn this off and give users the option to disable?

  ```
  trigger emailFollowers on FeedItem (after insert) {

          for (FeedItem f: trigger.new) {

              if (f.ParentID != null) {
              Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

              List<EntitySubscription> followers = [select id, subscriberid, subscriber.name, subscriber.email from EntitySubscription where parentid = :f.ParentID];

              String[] toAddresses = new List<String>();


              for (EntitySubscription follower : followers) {
                  toAddresses.add(follower.subscriber.email);
              }

              mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
              //mail.setTemplateID(templateId.Id);

              mail.setSubject('New Chatter Post ');

              mail.setPlainTextBody(f.body);


              Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
              }
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: Doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose of chatter? If they're already following the record, they would presumably see the chatter feed post.

Comment: this is for users not checking their chatter feed very often so the email notifications are needed.

Comment: Oh, and I take it you think those same users will check their growing numbers of emails instead? My apologies, I couldn't resist the commentary since users also can receive chatter email summaries. ;)

Comment: wait but do chatter email summaries include updates for posts that they are following cause that would be ideal but they dont seem to?

Comment: I'm not a big chatter user, but summaries would generally include everything in a user's feed that they're subscribed to. Off hand it really does seem to me that you're duplicating something that already exists in SF.

Comment: Nope I can confirm that posts on items you follow arent included in any of the digest emails.  They only include:    Follows
  Follows me   
 
  
  Posts on my profile   
  Shares a post I made   
  Likes a post or a comment I made   
 
 
  Comments on my status or a change I made   
  Comments on a post on my profile   
  Comments after me   
  Comments on an item I bookmarked   
  Comments on an item I like   
 
  
  Mentions me in a post   
  Mentions me in a comment   
  Sends me a message   
  Endorses me on a topic

Comment: Good information to know. Sounds like you may want to filter your users to send the email to by whether they subscribe to a digest.

Comment: yea but that would mean creating custom fields for the user and a custom set of settings which is what i was trying to avoid.... ohh well.  Really surprised its not included

Comment: @KeithMancuso Were you able to achieve this? I am having the same requirement to send notification to chatter followers on every post to the record.

Comment: Sadly no we ended up going with a custom object where they can add records to which trigger instead of chatter which is a bummer since it seemed so close.  Would love to hear if anyone else is able to do it with chatter, or if salesforce ever offers it built in